# How to get the index of row when using .apply() in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, apply

I have a dataframe containing rows of lists, something like this:

```
In [11]: import pandas as pd

In [12]: str1 = 'The weight of a apple'
         str2 = 'Apple MacBook release date news and rumors'

         list1 = ['DET', 'NOUN', 'ADP', 'DET', 'NOUN']
         list2 = ['PROPN', 'NOUN', 'NOUN', 'NOUN', 'CCONJ', 'PROPN']

         df = pd.DataFrame(
             {
                 'col1': [str1, str2],
                 'col2': [list1, list2]        
             }
         )

         df

Out[12]: 
                                         col1                                        col2  
0                       The weight of a apple                 [DET, NOUN, ADP, DET, NOUN]
1  Apple MacBook release date news and rumors     [PROPN, NOUN, NOUN, NOUN, CCONJ, PROPN]
```

I am using a user-defined function to check for the occurrence of the keyword 'apple' in *col1* and get its position value, by making use of .apply() in Pandas. I am then trying to get the item in the list from *col2* matching the position value.

However, I have no clue how to get the index of the **current row** when the .apply() function is looping through my user-defined function.

This is what I'm trying to do.

```
In [14]: # Find occurance of 'apple' keyword
         def find_apple(text):
           keyword = 'apple'
           words = text.lower().split(' ')

           if keyword in words:    
             word_index = words.index(keyword)
             value = df.col2[curr_row_index][word_index]
             print(value)
           else:
             print('None')    

         # Function call using .apply() 
         df['col3'] = df['col1'].apply(find_apple)
```

I want to know how I could get the value for *curr_row_index*, so as to get an iterable over rows of the dataframe.

I have tried using df.index and row.name to no avail. Maybe someone can explain what I'm doing wrong.

P.S. I am new here and this is my first time asking a question, hence apologies in advance for any missing information.

Comment: What do you expect 'col3' to be using your example DataFrame?

Comment: 'col3 would be having the item from the list in 'col2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor your function to operate on rows then use `axis=1` when calling apply:

```
def f(row):
    #print(row.name,row.col1,row.col2)
    value = None
    if 'apple' in row.col1.lower():
        idx = row.col1.lower().split().index('apple')
#        print(row.col2[idx])
        value = row.col2[idx]
    return value

df['col3' ] = df.apply(f,axis=1)
```

Using your example DataFrame:

```
In [34]: print(df.to_string())
                                         col1                                     col2   col3
0                       The weight of a apple              [DET, NOUN, ADP, DET, NOUN]   NOUN
1  Apple MacBook release date news and rumors  [PROPN, NOUN, NOUN, NOUN, CCONJ, PROPN]  PROPN

In [35]:
```